# Carlos Ag Excel Xml Writer in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually i tried to export an excel file using Carlos Ag ExcelXmlWriter.

**Sample Code**

```
         public void ExportToExcel()
    {
        Workbook book = new Workbook();
        Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add("Sample");
        WorksheetRow row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
        row.Cells.Add("Hello World");
        book.Save(@"c:\test.xls");
    }
```

This is the above code i tried. But its not exporting an excel file. Even its not showing error also. So, how can i overcome from this issue? 
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But above code is correct, they are referring from this website http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/, but in application program namespace also necessary is mentioned below:

```
    using CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter;

    class TestApp {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Workbook book = new Workbook();
            Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add("Sample");
            WorksheetRow row =  sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
            row.Cells.Add("Hello World");
            book.Save(@"c:\test.xls");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, i mentioned the namespace also. But still its not exporting. Its just executes and return the page that's it. Not exporting any xls file

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
please try for another method, mentioned below

Private void ExportDatasettoExcel(DataSet dsExcel)
{
            //Add a workbook
        string fileName = @"C:\Sample.xls";
            CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.Workbook book = new CarlosAg.ExcelXmlWriter.Workbook();

            // Specify which Sheet should be opened and the size of window by default
            book.ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheetIndex = 1;
            book.ExcelWorkbook.WindowTopX = 100;
            book.ExcelWorkbook.WindowTopY = 200;
            book.ExcelWorkbook.WindowHeight = 7000;
            book.ExcelWorkbook.WindowWidth = 8000;

            // Some optional properties of the Document
            book.Properties.Author = "Murali";
            book.Properties.Title = "Excel Export";
            book.Properties.Created = DateTime.Now;

        //Add styles to the workbook 
            WorksheetStyle s31 =book.Styles.Add("s31");
            s31.Font.FontName = "Tahoma";
            s31.Font.Size = 8;
            s31.Font.Color = "#000000";
            s31.Alignment.Horizontal = StyleHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            s31.Alignment.Vertical = StyleVerticalAlignment.Center;
            s31.Alignment.WrapText = true;
            s31.Borders.Add(StylePosition.Bottom, LineStyleOption.Continuous, 1);
            s31.Borders.Add(StylePosition.Left, LineStyleOption.Continuous, 1);
            s31.Borders.Add(StylePosition.Right, LineStyleOption.Continuous, 1);
            s31.Borders.Add(StylePosition.Top, LineStyleOption.Continuous, 1);
            s31.NumberFormat = "@";

            // Add styles for header of the Workbook
            WorksheetStyle style = book.Styles.Add("HeaderStyle");
            style.Font.FontName = "Tahoma";
            style.Font.Size = 12;
            style.Font.Bold = true;
            style.Alignment.Horizontal = StyleHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            style.Font.Color = "White";
            style.Interior.Color = "Blue";
            style.Interior.Pattern = StyleInteriorPattern.DiagCross;


            // Add a Worksheet with some data
            Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets.Add("Sample Data");
            // we can optionally set some column settings
            sheet.Table.Columns.Add(new WorksheetColumn(100));
            sheet.Table.Columns.Add(new WorksheetColumn(100));
            sheet.Table.Columns.Add(new WorksheetColumn(250));

            //Add row with some properties
            WorksheetRow row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
            row.Index = 0;
            row.Height = 26;
            row.AutoFitHeight = false;

        //Add header text for the columns   
            WorksheetCell wcHeader = new WorksheetCell("Column 1", "HeaderStyle");
            row.Cells.Add(wcHeader);
            wcHeader = new WorksheetCell("Column 2", "HeaderStyle");
            row.Cells.Add(wcHeader);
            wcHeader = new WorksheetCell("Column 3", "HeaderStyle");
            row.Cells.Add(wcHeader);           

        //Loop through each table in dataset
            for (int i = 0; i < dsExcel.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
        //Loop through each row in datatable                
                    foreach (DataRow dtrrow in dsExcel.Tables[i].Rows)
                    {                   
            //Add row to the excel sheet
            row = sheet.Table.Rows.Add();
                        row.Height = 30;
                        row.AutoFitHeight = false;
            //Loop through each column
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dsExcel.Tables[i].Columns)
                        {

                                WorksheetCell wc = new WorksheetCell(dtrrow[col.ColumnName].ToString(), DataType.String, "s31");
                                row.Cells.Add(wc);                            
                        }
                    }                
            }
        //Save the work book
            book.Save(fileName);
}
```